# Using NonlinearModelFit to fit data with errors

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, data

Assume we have some data of measurements

```
SeedRandom[9];
data = Table[{i,2*(1 + 5*RandomReal[])*Exp[-0.01*(1 + RandomReal[])*i]}, {i, {0, 100, 200, 400, 700}}];
```

and measurement errors associated to it

```
errors = 10^# & /@ Range[0, -4, -1];
```

Ignoring the weights in a first step, the fitting works very well:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Exp[-b*x], {a, b}, x, Method -> "NMinimize"];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Medium], 
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 700}, PlotRange -> Full], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Fit without measurement errors]

Now, according to [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/FitModelsWithMeasurementErrors.html) how-to, we can include the measurement errors to the fitting procedure:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*Exp[-b*x], {a, b}, x, Weights -> 1/errors^2, VarianceEstimatorFunction -> (1 &), Method -> "NMinimize"];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Medium], 
Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 700}, PlotRange -> Full], PlotRange -> All]
```

Clearly, the obtained fit is much worse.

[image: Fit with measurement errors]

**My questions are**:

1. What is the objective function in `NonlinearModelFit` when introducing weights? The how-to says: "It is important to note that weights do not change the fitting or error estimates", but obviously the fit is changed. Thus, the weights have to be a part of the objective functions, which is minimized.
2. How can I obtain a better fit with introduced weights? I was playing around with the `NMinimize` options `"NelderMead"`, `"RandomSearch"`, `"SimulatedAnnealing"` and `"DifferentialEvolution"`, but up to this point none of them was able to reproduce the fit obtained by ignoring the measurement errors.

Comment: isn't mathematica doing the right thing? The error on the first points are gigantic so it just ignores them...

Comment: It also occurs with smaller errors. I edited my question, thanks.

Comment: The weights you choose for the last points are 10^8 times the one you use for the first point. What else would you expect than that the first point is almost completely ignored?

Comment: I would expect that the residual on the first point is smaller than or at least close to the error. Since the measurement of a big quantity will yeald greater errors than a small quantity, the fit should account for this effect.

Answer (score 5):

The `Weights` option operates on a point-by-point basis to say how important that individual point is to the complete fit. Let's take some simple data that obviously don't fit on a line and try to fit them with a line. With equal weighting, you get a compromise:

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 2.5}, {3, 3}};
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, Weights -> {1, 1, 1}]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 7}]]
```

If you weight the second point a lot (in comparison to the other two then it moves the fit closer to the second point.

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, Weights -> {1, 100, 1}]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm2[x], {x, 0, 7}]]
```

while if you weight the 1st and 3rd more heavily, it almost ignores the second completely:

```
nlm3 = NonlinearModelFit[data, a x + b, {a, b}, x, Weights -> {10, 1, 10}]
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[nlm3[x], {x, 0, 7}]]
```

[image]

So -- what is it actually doing? You'd have to ask someone from Wolfram to know for sure, but it seems highly likely it's something like this:

Minimize ( $w_1*(f[x]-p_1)^2 + w_2*(f[x]-p_2)^2 + w_3*(f[x]-p_3)^2 )$

where the $p_i$ are the points and the $f[x]$ is your function. The weights are then proportional to the values you give in the `Weights` option. For instance, by setting $w_2=100$, you have made the fit to point $p_2$ much more important as it chooses the parameters. Now obviously, this example is for a simple linear fit (here you don't need the full power of `NonlinearModelFit` but it would be surprising if it operated fundamentally differently for different kinds of equation.

Comment: I also think that the objective function is something like the above-mentioned. Maybe even the `"StandardizedResiduals"`, see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html